# Can two different set of independent vectors span same plane?

Tags: vector-spaces, independence

Can two different set of independent vectors span the same plane? let's say two independent basis vectors v1 and v2 span a plane P1. Can we find different set of independent vectors v3 and v4 that span the same plane?

Comment: Sure.   You should have no difficulty finding many pairs of vectors which span $\mathbb R^2$, for example.

Comment: Give one concrete example, $\left\{\vec{i},\vec{j}\right\}$ and $\left\{\vec{i}+\vec{j},\vec{i}-\vec{j}\right\}$